# Referencing the BuildNumber from a inside a TFS MSBuild project

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I'm trying to set-up a TFS build.  I've customised the default TFS2013 workflow to obtain BuildDetail just before the MSBuild commmand.  However, I now get a build error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. 
>   Switch: not
>
> For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"

My command line arguments are as follows:

```
/target:publish;/p:PublishDir=\\Server1\PublishDir\;PublishingURL=https://www.website.com
```

I've played about with this, as I've read several questions on here along the same lines that point to a space, quote or a slash in the wrong place.

I've also changed the MSBuild command to look like this:

```
String.Format("/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:BuildNumber={1} {0}", AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)("MSBuildArguments", String.Empty), BuildDetail.BuildNumber)
```

My target is to access the BuildNumber from within the proj file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to diagnose this?

EDIT:

Based on the answer by @sburgess123 below, using `$(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)` causes an exception in the build.  The exception isn't massively helpful; but it's here:

> Run MSBuild
>
> > Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build.
> >     You can find more specific information about the cause of this error
> >     in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException) Exception
> >     Stack Trace:    at
> >     System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext
> >     context)    at
> >     System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
> >     instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
> >     at
> >     System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
> >     executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Having looked, I can't find an actual error anywhere in the logs, but if I remove the reference to `$(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)` it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the build process template to do this. In 2013 there are a bunch of environment variables you have access to. See the section 'use environment variable data in msbuild' in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh850448.aspx

Comment: It looks like you're right - however, once I add /p:BuildNumber="$(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)" to my build, it crashes

Comment: In what way does it crash?